# Ranges in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am quite new to VBA and trying to create an excel template that uses VBA to change a path and automatically gather data from other workbooks. Basically creating a master document to store the information.

At the moment I am using the following code:

```
Sub CallOtherWB()

  Dim JobNumber As String

  JobNumber = Range("C4").Value

  With Range("D4")
     .Formula = "='Y:\Public\QA Other\Scorecards\Copy of Scorecard v0.6 " & 
       JobNumber & ".xlsm'!Total"
 End With

End Sub
```

However I haven't figured out how to make the range go through C4:C50 and grab the data entered there to edit `"='Y:\Public\QA Other\Scorecards\Copy of Scorecard v0.6 " & JobNumber & ".xlsm'!Total"` which would go in D4:D50.

I searched through other questions and tried to do a sort of loop but was not able to understand how to make the range work.
To summarize I am using that code to enter the information in the C column and for that information to replace the "JobNumber" part in the D column so that it has the correct file name.

Please let me know if I need to clarify this further and thanks in advance for the help. 
This is also my first question in Stackoverflow so I apologize for any mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked for me.

```
Sub CallOtherWB()

Dim JobNumber As String
Dim srcCell As String

Dim id As Integer

    For id = 4 To 50
        srcCell = "C" & id

        JobNumber = Range(srcCell).Value

        Range("D" & id).Value = "='C:\Users\banand\Desktop\test\[" & JobNumber & ".xlsx]Total'!D4"
    Next

End Sub
```

Trick here is to set the file path accurately. You can try replacing the file path as below and test to see if it works.

```
    Range("D4").Value = "='Y:\Public\QA Other\Scorecards\[Copy of Scorecard v0.6 " & JobNumber & ".xlsm]Total'!D4"
```

If the above doesn't work, you can try to key in the below value in a cell, D3 (or some other cell of your choice in the target excel) with just the complete filepath as below to see if the filepath part of the code is translating correctly.

```
    ='Y:\Public\QA Other\Scorecards\[Copy of Scorecard v0.6 " & JobNumber & ".xlsm]Total'!D4:D50"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just so that you know, I have tested it with the source file closed and it worked perfect. :-)

Comment: I understand what this code does and I appreciate the help. However I am trying to get the information that I enter in the C column of the master workbook to replace the job number part of the path which is in the D column of the master workbook. The cell is it referencing(Total) has a number which I need to use in the master book and i need it to be updated as we work in the other workbooks. This seems to help me update all the D column but with the same value in C4 when I need it to update as C5 to D5, C6 to D6 and so on.

Comment: @Josh, Have a look at the modified code, it now iterates through the C column from rows 4 to 50. If this is what you needed, please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Looping is overkill.  By putting the value into a variable you are fixing it per cell.  This is inefficient for your purposes.

```
Sub CallOtherWB()

  Range("D4:D50").FormulaR1C1= "='Y:\Public\QA Other\Scorecards\Copy of Scorecard v0.6 "" & RC[-1] & "".xlsm'!Total"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried using that code, I am not sure what the formula does and when I run it, it just comes up with the RC[-1]. It seems like maybe I am missing something? What I need is for that part that says RC[-1] to be replaced with the info I have in the C column

Answer (score 0):

I believe a path is not correct, it should be like this (please see where are `'` characters and exclamation mark):

`='C:\path_to_directory\[file_name.xlsx]sheet_name'!A1`

What you want to achieve can be done without VBA. Please have a look at [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function. You'll need to enter following formula in your `D4` cell:

`=INDIRECT("'Y:\Public\QA Other\Scorecards\[Copy of Scorecard v0.6 " & C4 & ".xlsm]Total'!A1"`

Comment: The problem with using the INDIRECT function is that the excel needs to be open for it to work. So I choose to look at VBA in order to be able to get it from closed excels since we will continue creating the documents and just change that one number in the file name

Comment: What about the "RefreshAll" functionality?

Comment: It would still give the #REF error unless the other excel workbooks were open.